# Description list - How to put the whole paragraph in the same start line?

Tags: description

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{description}
       \item[a)] Perhaps the single most commonly used application is the measurement of vibration modes in order to compare these with corresponding data produced by a finite element or other theoretical model.For this specific application, all that we require from the the test are:...    
    \end{description}    
  \end{document}
```

and it produces the following PDF:[image]

I want that the second and the third lines start from where the first of the paragraph 'Perhaps' start.

Comment: This looks more like `enumerate` - why do you want to use a description list without something to describe?

Comment: Because then I have to use the different cases: a, b, c..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more sophisticated ways to customize enumerated lists but for the purpose you are describing here, the `enumerate` package should help:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]%for small alpha-characters 
    \item Perhaps the single most commonly used application is the measurement of vibration modes in order to compare these with corresponding data produced by a finite element or other theoretical model.For this specific application, all that we require from the the test are:
    \item test itme 1
    \item test item 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
       \item Perhaps the single most commonly used application is the measurement of vibration modes in order to compare these with corresponding data produced by a finite element or other theoretical model.For this specific application, all that we require from the the test are:...    
       \item Perhaps the single most commonly used application is the measurement of vibration modes in order to compare these with corresponding data produced by a finite element or other theoretical model.For this specific application, all that we require from the the test are:...    
    \end{enumerate}    
  \end{document}
```